# Apscheduler Job Serialization not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

We are setting up a scheduler based on Apscheduler, the problem is we are not able to serialize the Jobs.

Here's a structure of what we want.

A class Base, with its method, this is the class to be run

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, bim):
      self.b = bim
      pass

    def print_some(self):
      print "Some bout to go down"
```

A class BS from whom the class Base execution will be scheduled

```
from base import Base
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
import logging

logging.basicConfig()

jobstores = {'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='url_to_DB')}

class BS(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
       self.scheduler.configure(jobstores=jobstores)
       self.scheduler.start()
       self.base = Base()


    def print_some(self):
       print "ngnf"

    def add_job(self):
       self.scheduler.add_job(Base.print_some, 'interval', minutes=1)


BS().add_job()
```

But when I run the code, I have a problem passing an argument to the constructor

```
ERROR:apscheduler.executors.default:Job "Base.print_some (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2016-05-24 18:16:27 CEST)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 112, in run_job
retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
TypeError: unbound method print_some() must be called with Base instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I have tried this

```
self.scheduler.add_job(Base.print_some, 'interval', args=[Base()], kwargs=dict(self=Base()), seconds=1)
```

and this

```
self.scheduler.add_job(Base.print_some, 'interval', args=[self.base], kwargs=dict(self.base), seconds=1)
```

None of them worked.

What am I missing, or should do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example can't work as you have conflicting positional and keyword arguments. The third I assume doesn't work since self.base is not an iterable.
Have you tried only passing the instance as a positional argument?

Comment: Oh Alex, thanks for helping out on Google Groups,
I finally went with :

     `def add_job(self, num):
           self.scheduler.add_job(base.print_it, 'interval', seconds=1)`